# unit test android

Tags: android, unit-testing

Unit testing android application is often more difficult than expected because there are classes that do not have a public constructor (like NotificationManager) and classes that have methods that is not possible to override like Context.getText.

For NotificationManager I used a delegator. I would do the same for the context but that means that in all the classes that use the context (many) I need to use my own context that can't even be derived from Context. Then whenever I need to pass the context to an Android API I need to get the real context from within my wrapper.

Is this correct? Is there another way to do it? What is the rationale of having those methods declared as final?
Is there someone that has really written unit tests for big applications for Android?

**EDIT**

I found the reason why the getText method is defined as final: it's a template method. So it is enough to override the called non final methods

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827139/android-junit-define-a-different-application-subclass) that works but it is a bit weird

Comment: I also use customized android.app.Application and think it is quite handy when come into Test Project, You can define many application-wide variables here and get/set these variable via getter/setter in Test Project, to obtain a highly configurable application object, much like a mock context. What is a bit weird? Perhaps you can open another question for further discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is a little bit vague so I am going to write a long answer.

> there are classes that do not have a public constructor (like NotificationManager)

Because there are some system-wide resources/components (for instance NotificationManager) which Android doesn't like application to construct/instantiate on demand, instead, these resources are centralized and managed by system and application should always use system provided API to acquire them.

> and classes that have methods that is not possible to override like Context.getText

Generally in Java, method marked as final means they are protected by API and API developer doesn't want the default behaviour to be overridden by application developer. In particular for this method Context.getText(), it actually use Template method pattern, check out herschel's comment below and the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/content/Context.java?av=f#271) for more details.

### Then the question is how do we properly test our code written by using these android context based resources/components?

The answer given by Android SDK is Test Project (via InstrumentationTestRunner). Generally, when using InstrumentationTestRunner, behind the sense, system will install both test.apk (build from Test Project) and app.apk (build from Application Project), and use test.apk manipulate app.apk for testing. **This is happened Regardless of whether you use AndroidTestCase API (referred as JUnit in diagram below) or InstrumentationTestCase API (referred as Instrumentation in diagram below)** The corresponding testable android context based resoures/components (i.e. Activity, NotificationManager or TextView) are all acquired from the real running app.apk instance. In case you create/use your own MockContext in Test Project, you can see from the diagram that mock object is injected into the running application by InstrumentationTestRunner.

[image]

The drawback of using instrumentation test is about efficiency, it goes into the complete running life cycle (start emulator -> install and start both test.apk and app.apk and fire InstrumentationTestRunner) even though you just need test a single method from a single class (as you mentioned in comment). I agree with Ollie, it is a hostile design.

This is where [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html) come in and play, quouting from their website: *Robolectric is a unit test framework that de-fangs the Android SDK jar so you can test-drive the development of your Android app. Tests run inside the JVM on your workstation in seconds.*

From my own experience, I have an application consists of around 10 activities and several Service with some other custom views/widgets doing mainly http communication with remote server, and use both instrumentation test (via Test Project) and Robolectic testing Android Context based code. I can pretty much test almost every single class/public method of my application as long as time is allowed.

Comment: Do you mean that to test a method I need to run the application? I wanted to test the method in isolation so without really calling the Android sdk. By the way there is a MockContext in the android sdk that is supposed to be used to mock the context during tests. The problem is that I didn't manage to use it because of the final methods.

Comment: in your answer you say: it goes into the complete running life cycle (start emulator -> install and open both test.apk and app.apk and run instrumentation test). What do you mean with "open"? What I have seen is that if I do not use the real context I can run unit test without running the application. I just need to install it. Only when I call Context.getText my class that extends "Application" is created (calling onCreate). I'm now installing Robolectric.

Comment: In case if you write your test code using Android Test Project and run Android Test Project via InstrumentationTestRunner, The answer is yes. If you wanted to test the method in isolation so without really calling the Android sdk, then highly recommend consider using Robolectric. AFAIK, Robolectric is the only solution available at the moment which let you test Android context based resources/components by without running the actual application (via InstrumentationTestRunner) on an emulator or real device.

Comment: I'm using AntroidTestCase and the application is tarted anyway. I found the reason why the getText method is final: it's a template method. To stub it it is enough to override the called methods

Comment: I would set it as accepted but you need to correct the things that are not correct: the reason why getText is final, the fact that with AndroidTestCase the application is not started. Honestly I think it is not correct to say that you rarely need to mock the context. But that is just you opinion...

Answer (score 0):

Android is pretty hostile to testing in many respects.

You might want to take a look at Roboelectric
http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

I assume you've read these:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/helloandroid_test.html

Answer (score 0):

The *TestCase classes that Android provides for you should be able to solve the testing issues you are encountering. In most of these instances it will spawn a context for you that you can override if you wish. I would suggest starting there, or asking more specific questions about how you would test one thing or another.

Comment: The problem is that if you haven't wrapped the Context class in your code, I don't see a way to solve the problem by working only on the testcase. The methods that are final can't be stubbed. In my case for example what happens is that the application is started when I'm just testing a method of a class.